# How to get year fom a date using DateTime::createFromFormat()?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get day, month, and year from a date but it doesn't work. I always get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in printtest.php on line 4

This is my `printtest.php` code. I got an error. How to fix this? Check live demo [here](http://daplonline.in/print/dateview.php).

```
<?php
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", '$dob');
    $year1 = $date->format("Y");
    $day1 = $date->format("d");
    $mon3 = $date->format("m");
    echo $year1;
?>
```

Comment: `createFromFormat("Y-m-d", '$dob')` — You're using single-quotes. Variables do not get interpolated when they're in single-quotes. Drop the quotes from there (or use double-quotes instead).

Comment: i added double quotes but not working getting same error :(

Comment: The datepicker sends the date in `m-d-Y` format. You're using `Y-m-d` instead. Change it to use `m-d-Y`: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", $dob);`.

Comment: Dear @AmalMurali why you marked my question as duplicated ?? this question and datepicker is not same check

Comment: @user3705511 I dont think this is a duplicate.  You had a format error as well as the quoted variable error.  Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя The linked duplicate does not address the problem here. It only talks about the broad "member function ... on non-object" error message, which is very vague and not of any particular use to the OP (or anyone else reading the question).

Comment: @DanSherwin my question have both error quoted and fatal error so both question is no duplicated check the DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", $dob); this side error solved

Comment: @NullPoiиteя you maked my question as duplicate without read or tested it's not fair in stackoverflow web..check the website faculty and rules thank you

Comment: And the change is to `d-m-Y` and not `m-d-Y`.  Look at sample site.  Day is before the month.

Comment: yes @DanSherwin my problem already solved by amal murali's answer :) anyway thak you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around your dob variable as Alessandro said, but also,
according to your sample site, the input field is in the format `d-m-Y`, and the format you are passing is `Y-m-d`.

So change

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", '$dob');
```

to be

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $dob);
```

Comment: my problem already solved by amal murali's answer :) anyway thak you

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below code to get the Year

<?php
    $dob    = $_POST['dob'];
    $date   = explode("-",$dob);
    $year1  = $date[2];
    echo $year1;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Variable interpolation only happens in double-quoted strings so this code is attempeting to parse the string "$dob" as a Y-m-d date, rather than the string contained in the variable `$dob`.  This can be fixed by changing `DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", '$dob')` to `DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "$dob")`

Also, since you may not have control over the values posted to your script you should check that `DateTime::createFromFormat()` returned an object (it returns false on failure) before attempting to operate on its return value, e.g.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "$dob");
if (!$date)
{
   echo "Invalid dob (YYYY-mm-dd): $dob";
   exit;
}

$year1 = $date->format("Y");
$day1 = $date->format("d");
$mon3 = $date->format("m");
echo $year1;
```

This way if a dob that can't be parsed as a Y-m-d date is posted you won't get the same fatal error but rather a more useful "Invalid dob" message.